# How to display image as slide in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

hi i have an array of images

```
$scope.allimages = [{
        'src' : 'img/home1.png'
    }, {
        'src' : 'img/home2.png'
    }, {
        'src' : 'img/home3.png'
    },{
        'src' : 'img/home4.png'
    }];
```

i need to display this image in a page one by one i.e. one image at a time.one image display for 30 sec after the second image shows like that 
How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`ion-slide-box`**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSlideBox/), then you need to set `slide-interval` to `30000` to change image in 30 seconds, its default to 4 seconds.

**Markup**

```
<ion-slide-box slide-interval="30000">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in allimages">
    <img class="custom-class" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.it works as slider. but i need show first image and then need to hide that and then need to display second one .not sliding

Answer (score 1):

You could use ion-slide-box, then you need to set slide-interval to 30000 to change image in 30 seconds, its default to 4 seconds.
 TRY THIS

```
<ion-slide-box auto-play='true' does-continue='true' slide-intervel='30000'>
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in allImages">
    <img class="custom-class" ng-src="{{img.src}}"/>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: does-continue='true' is optional for image slideshow loop continues